# Are .NET string resources interned?

Tags: c#, .net, string-interning

All of our web pages' strings come from [resources](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227427.aspx).  Sometimes resources are shared across pages, which seems efficient but creates an issue when somebody changes a resource without realizing how many places it is used.  I am tempted to say to the team-- never ever share resources, every string gets its own resource symbol.  But on the other hand, that could be a waste of space, right?

A .resx file is of course just XML, but it compiles into a binary format.  I am guessing there would need to be a manifest and a symbol table plus a series of blob entries containing the resources.  If there are two resources with the same value, there will be two symbols in the manifest.  But will there be two blobs?

Or will a string resource be [interned](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning) just like a string constant?

Comment: Have you tried just testing it? `ReferenceEquals(GetThing(...), GetThing(...))` ? Note also that it might be *cached* (as a reference) at some level without being formally *interned*, but: the difference might be nominal

Comment: This question does not seem to have any practical benefit. Surely this is an implementation detail; it's not documented and could change tomorrow. And that's not even counting that the word "resource" means a number of different things, even restricted to the context of a .NET program. And frankly, the question doesn't make much sense; what we normally think of as "resources" typically cannot be modified at run-time. An exception is elements of a WPF `ResourceDictionary`. But even there, the `string` object itself is never modified; `string` is immutable. You need to clarify and narrow this.

Comment: @Peter, The benefit is smaller disk and memory footprint as well as smaller working set.  Interning is something that is done only to immutable string constants, so I do not understand why you think it matters that resources cannot be modified at run time.  And I think mentioning `.resx` makes it unambiguous what is meant by "resources."

Comment: _"The benefit is smaller disk and memory footprint as well as smaller working set"_ -- you misunderstand my comment. It's not that interning has no practical benefit. It's that your question _about_ interning has no practical benefit. The documentation tells you both what you _need_ to know and what you can _rely_ on knowing. Even if someone had an answer to the implementation detail you are asking about, it's not information you can use reliably or with confidence.

Comment: I think you are overstating your case.  Interning is a compile-time activity so it'll be completely reliable until I upgrade to the next version of Visual Studio.